# Alternative to setInterval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, setinterval

I'm working on a website in which notifications and comments are reloaded every 3 seconds. I implemented this using `setInterval`--as Facebook's React Tutorial suggested--but I quickly realized that this may be inefficient.

I'm currently using Ruby on Rails and React. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You can use websockets as an alternative to polling. In Rails you have  [ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable), which will be included in Rails 5 and makes these kind of features trivial to implement.

Comment: Is it possible to use ActionCable without updating to Rails 5?

Comment: @Novice Rails 5. I use it with Rails 4 just fine, don't know if previous version will work.

Comment: Yes, there a couple of tutorials out there on how to integrate this with an existing rails 4 project.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is pusher.com which I have found is the lowest cost quick integration.  If u r using rails and react u might want to check out http://reactrb.org